# Selenium - Clique em Input com evento Onclick() não funciona

Tags: javascript, python, html5, selenium-webdriver, testes-automatizados

estou tendo problemas ao tentar clicar em um botão (Input) HTML com Selenium no Internet Explore.
Ao executar o comando `click()` nada acontece nem mesmo erros são apresentados. Segue abaixo a disposição do código HTML do Botão e em seguida meu código em Python.

```
<td>
<input type = "button" class='botao' value='adicionar todos' onclick="AdicionarTodos()">
<input type = "button" class='botao' value='remover todos' onclick="RemoverTodos()">
</td>
```

OBS: Desejo clicar na primeira opção "adicionar todos"

```
add_todos_botao = driver.find_element_by_xpath("XPATH")
add_todos_botao.click()
```

OBS:o `XPATH` do objeto fo capturado pela inspeção do google chrome e utilizado no Internet Explore.

Comment: <td>
<input type = "button" class='botao' value='adicionar todos' onclick="AdicionarTodos()">
<input type = "button" class='botao' value='remover todos' onclick="RemoverTodos()">
</td>

Comment: Poderia adicionar a mensagem de erro que ocorre?

Comment: @Danizavtz, não retorna erro algum. O botão apenas não realiza a ação esperada.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode user o seguinte método, ja que com o analise do Chrome, a página pode muda estrutura e estar posicionando o seletor em outro lado, então é melhor ser mais específicos

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="adicionar todos"]')